# remove one page layout from phtml page

Tags: magento-1.9, layout

missly we did some  changes and now one of our phtml page is displaying as one page layout : [here](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/marketplace/marketplaceaccount/myproductslist/)

we want to remove that . but we have no idea which xml file we need to look.

IS there any way we can find in which xml file we added the code to make it 1 column layout.? we checked in `local.xml`. its not there

Comment: can you share page url?

Comment: you cann check [here](test.collagekingapp.com/marketplace/marketplaceaccount/myproductslist)

Comment: Add your layout under this <marketplace_marketplaceaccount_myproductslist> in local.xml

Comment: <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>

Comment: @LearningMagento it didt worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for these two tags in module.xml or local.xml

```
<marketplace_marketplaceaccount_myproductslist>

</marketplace_marketplaceaccount_myproductslist>
```

These should be the once you changed

Comment: seems its some other problem, its in local.xml file only, but when i move the file through "git" , its not working in another site

Comment: check there module xml because magento first read `module.xml` the `local.xml` and make sure your cache is disabled or refresh the cache after the changes..

Comment: sorry, i copied the marketplace.xml file through git , but still its not working in another site

Comment: did  you check the theme they are and also after that refresh the cache?

Comment: cache was disabled, both sites have exactly same code. if i update the code from local.xml , than it will work in 1st site.
but in another site , its not working. i will check in theme.

Comment: check you are making change in correct theme i can that is the issue.

Comment: yes, i am sure about the theme.